# MAC Catalina Upgrade error : The disk doesn't use the GUID partition

Tags: mac, macos, catalina, mac-pro

I have this problem  when I want to upgrade my MACOS from Yosemit to Catalina

[image]
My pc specs are as fallow:

[image: png]

When i'm going to volume I can't select anything 
[image]

And if I go to erase, the same problem happens

[image]

When I diskutil list & diskutil cs list

```
ADMINs-MBP-2:~ ADMIN$ diskutil list & diskutil cs list
[1] 641
No CoreStorage logical volume groups found
ADMINs-MBP-2:~ ADMIN$ /dev/disk0
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:     FDisk_partition_scheme                        *251.0 GB   disk0
   1:                  Apple_HFS Untitled                251.0 GB   disk0s1

[1]+  Done                    diskutil list
ADMINs-MBP-2:~ ADMIN$
```

Comment: Your disk is currently formatted as MBR which Catalina cannot use. TBH I don't know how you even managed to do this, Macs don't boot from MBR at all, they need GUID. Is this a new drive you're trying to get macOS on for the first time? If you can get to Terminal [Applications/Utilities] then please add the result of `diskutil list` & `diskutil cs list` to your question [one will be possibly empty, the other useful].

Comment: Added! The Mac is a recomposed Mac from the fabric. That should have happened. Thxx for the help.

Comment: OK, so we're seeing a single MBR [FDisk] disk, with an HFS partition - where do your earlier pictures come from? What are you booted from, to even get that data? if you've managed to boot from that disk [& I really don't understand how] then you're going to have to reboot to Internet Recovery & wipe it completely to get Catalina on it.

Comment: I may be wrong - this claims you can boot a Mac from an MBR disk, but you cannot install an OS to one directly - http://refit.sourceforge.net/myths/

Comment: I took the pictures from Disk Utilities while selecting the 251Gb Apple SSD. I don't have important information on the computer so there is an option where I can reinstall everything and fix it?

Comment: I think you are going to need a full Time Machine backup to get out of this one. I'm not absolutely certain if there may be another way round - so I'd wait & see if someone else has a better plan. I'd make certain to have a full backup anyway, in this instance, I cannot think how it could be done non-destructively & risk-free.